# ¿Cómo sincronizar 3 procesos fork() "2 hijos y un padre usando pipes"?¿Qué pipes cerrar y dónde?

Tags: c, pipe, posix

Tengo que comunicar un proceso padre y dos hijos suyos; no comprendo cómo cerrar los pipes ni usar `wait` o `waitpid`.
Saludos!

Esto es el core que llevo:

```
#include<unistd.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<fcntl.h>
#include<limits.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<sys/wait.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#define BUFF 500
#define LEE 0
#define ESC 1

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    int mayus_fk, mayus_pp[2], stt_ma;
    int cuent_fk, cuent_pp[2], stt_cu;
    int buff[BUFF],pa_lee;

    pipe(mayus_pp);
    if ( (mayus_fk=fork()) == 0 ){ /* hijo */
        printf("Soy el primer hijo (%d, hijo de %d)\n",  getpid(), getppid());
    }
    else{ /*  padre */
            pipe(cuent_pp);
        if ( (cuent_fk=fork()) == 0 ){ /* segundo hijo  */
            printf("Soy el segundo hijo (%d, hijo de %d)\n",  getpid(), getppid());
        }
        /* padre */
        while((pa_lee=read(0,buff,LEE))>0){
                write(1,buff,pa_lee);   
        }
            printf("Soy el segundo hijo (%d, hijo de %d)\n",  getpid(), getppid());

            waitpid(mayus_fk, &stt_ma, 0);/* Esperamos al primer hijo */
            printf("Error hijo mayus_fk: %s\n", strerror(errno));
            waitpid(cuent_fk, &stt_cu, 0);/* Esperamos al segundo hijo */
            //printf("Soy el padre (%d, hijo de %d)\n", getpid(), getppid());
            printf("Error hijo cuent_fk: %s\n", strerror(errno));
    }
    //sleep(10);
    return 0;
}
```

---

Muchas gracias Iván por tu ayuda; mi problema surge cuando tengo que trabajar con dos procesos hijos y un padre y leer de la entrada estandar.

```
#include<unistd.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<fcntl.h>
#include<limits.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<sys/wait.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#define BUFF 800
#define LEER 0
#define ESCR 1

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    int mayus_fk, mayus_pp[2], stt_ma,l_m,buf_m[BUFF];
    bzero(buf_m,BUFF);

    int cuent_fk, cuent_pp[2], stt_cu,l_c,buf_c[BUFF];
    bzero(buf_c,BUFF);

    int buff[BUFF],pa_lee;  int hijo;
    memset(buff,0,BUFF);


    pipe(mayus_pp);
    if ( (mayus_fk=fork()) == 0 ){ 


        close(mayus_pp[ESCR]);
        close(cuent_pp[LEER]);
        close(cuent_pp[ESCR]);
        /*************MAYUS hijo */
        close(mayus_pp[ESCR]);
        while((l_m=read(mayus_pp[LEER],buf_m,sizeof(BUFF)))>0){
                write(1,buf_m,l_m);
        }
        close(mayus_pp[LEER]);
        bzero(buf_m,BUFF);
        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);

    }
    else{ /*  padre */
            pipe(cuent_pp);
        if ( (cuent_fk=fork()) == 0 ){ 

            close(mayus_pp[ESCR]);
            close(cuent_pp[ESCR]);
            close(mayus_pp[LEER]);

            /************* CUENT hijo  */
            close(cuent_pp[ESCR]);
            while((l_c=read(cuent_pp[LEER],buf_c,sizeof(BUFF)))>0){
                write(1,buf_c,l_c);
            }
            close(cuent_pp[LEER]);
            bzero(buf_c,BUFF);
            exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);

        }

        /*######## PADRE #######*/
            close(cuent_pp[LEER]);
            close(mayus_pp[LEER]);

        while( (pa_lee=read(0,buff,sizeof(BUFF))) >0 ){
            //write(1,buff,pa_lee);

            write(mayus_pp[ESCR],buff,pa_lee);                  
            write(cuent_pp[ESCR],buff,pa_lee);     


        }
            close(cuent_pp[ESCR]);
            close(mayus_pp[ESCR]);
            wait(&hijo);
    printf("\n");
    printf("MSG hijo mayus_fk: %s\n", strerror(errno));
    printf("MSG hijo cuent_fk: %s\n", strerror(errno));
    }


    //sleep(5);
    return 0;
}

/*
 bzero(machine->mainMemory, size);
    memset(machine->mainMemory, 0, size);
*/
```

He cerrado en cada hijo los que no usa, lo mismo para el padre; pero al ejecutar el programa se generan más hijos.
¿Alguna recomendación?

Answer (score 1):

Los pipes se tratan como archivos... se cierran con **close()**.

wait() y waitpid() se usa por el padre para esperar a que los procesos hijos terminen y no se queden zombies.

Te voy a dejar un ejemplo muy simple aquí de un ejercicio que hice en su dia en la universidad. Espero que te sirva.

---

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
int main()
{   

    pid_t   hijo;
    int  estado_hijo;   
    int fd1[2];


    //iniciar la tuberia
    if(pipe(fd1)==-1 )
    {   
        perror("pipe"); 
        exit(-1);
    }

    //crear un proceso hijo
    if ((hijo =fork()) == -1) 
    { 
        perror("fork"); 
        exit(-1); 
    } 
    if (hijo==0) //contexto para el hijo
    {       
        close(fd1[1]);      
        char leer[100]; 


        while(strcmp(leer,"FIN")!=0)        
        {           
            //leer los nombres de los usuarios
            if(read(fd1[0], leer, sizeof(char)*100)!=-1)
            {           
                //hacer tiempo
                sleep(Tiempo_de_espera);            

                //mensaje para el usuario
                printf("**hola papa** SE HA TERMINADO EL PROCESO PARA -->(%s)\n", leer);                                        
            }               
        }           
        close(fd1[0]);      
        exit(0);    

    }
    else //contexto para el padre
    {   
        char  escribir[100];    
        close(fd1[0]);  

        //mientras no se introuzca la palabra FIN
        while(strcmp(escribir,"FIN")!=0)        
        {
            //introducir los nombres de los usuarios                            
            printf("\nIntroduzca un usuario = \n");                 
            if(scanf("%s",&escribir)!=0)
            {
                //mandarle el nombre del usuario al hijo        
                write(fd1[1],escribir,100);//           
            }
        }       

        close(fd1[1]);               
        waitpid(hijo, &estado_hijo, 0); 
    }

    printf("\n");
    exit(0);
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Iván por tu ayuda; mi problema surge cuando tengo que trabajar con dos procesos hijos y un padre y leer de la entrada estandar.

Comment: Por el momento lo que veo es que solo estás esperando a que termine el proceso de un hijo y no de los dos... voy a compilar tu código a ver si puedo verlo mas claro

Comment: No puedo compilarlo... estoy con windows y no existen las librerias que tengan Pipe, Fork y wait... en momentos así echo de menos a linux :-( ...  voy a ver si con solo leerlo detenidamente saco alguna conclusión.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba así a ver que tal... he corregido un par de cosas que creo que tenias mal... pero por desgracia no he podido compilarlo para verificar que funciona por el el tema de que estoy con windows.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int mayus_fk, mayus_pp[2], stt_ma,l_m,buf_m[BUFF];
    bzero(buf_m,BUFF);

    int cuent_fk, cuent_pp[2], stt_cu,l_c,buf_c[BUFF];
    bzero(buf_c,BUFF);

    int buff[BUFF],pa_lee;  int hijo;
    memset(buff,0,BUFF);


    pipe(mayus_pp);
    pipe(cuent_pp);

    if ( (mayus_fk=fork()) == 0 )
    {
        close(mayus_pp[ESCR]);///1
        close(cuent_pp[ESCR]);///1

        while((l_m=read(mayus_pp[LEER],buf_m,sizeof(BUFF)))>0)
        {
            write(1,buf_m,l_m);
        }

        close(mayus_pp[LEER]);///0
        close(cuent_pp[LEER]);///0

        bzero(buf_m,BUFF);
        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);

    }
    else/*  padre */
    {

        if ( (cuent_fk=fork()) == 0 )
        {

            close(mayus_pp[ESCR]);///1
            close(cuent_pp[ESCR]);///1

            while((l_c=read(cuent_pp[LEER],buf_c,sizeof(BUFF)))>0)
            {
                write(1,buf_c,l_c);
            }
            close(cuent_pp[LEER]);///0
            close(mayus_pp[LEER]);///0

            bzero(buf_c,BUFF);
            exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);

        }

        /*######## PADRE #######*/
            close(cuent_pp[LEER]);///0
            close(mayus_pp[LEER]);///0

        while( (pa_lee=read(0,buff,sizeof(BUFF))) >0 )
        {
            //write(1,buff,pa_lee);
            write(mayus_pp[ESCR],buff,pa_lee);
            write(cuent_pp[ESCR],buff,pa_lee);
        }

        close(cuent_pp[ESCR]);///1
        close(mayus_pp[ESCR]);///1

        wait(&hijo);
        wait(&cuent_fk);

    printf("\n");
    printf("MSG hijo mayus_fk: %s\n", strerror(errno));
    printf("MSG hijo cuent_fk: %s\n", strerror(errno));
    }

    //sleep(5);
    return 0;
}
```